# Favicon squished for browser only

Tags: html, css, favicon

[image] Not filling entire icon space.

[website](https://mrmajik45.github.io/)

The favicon on my website is squished. It only happens on browsers. It doesn't happen with the safari mask icon, windows 8/10 Tile icon, Android (Launcher) shortcut icon, or the iOS safari shortcut icon. Is there a way i can fix this?

Comment: Looks fine to me? What do you mean by squished?

Comment: @LennartHase Look at edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue may appear when your computer browser is cached ...
click on CNTROL + F5 on key bored to make hard refresh and add this code to  tag on your HTML PAGE assuming that your icon image on folder and  img/icon/(your favicon name) 
please resize your favicon to heiht : 16px  and width 16px and paste the below code

```
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/icon/favicon.png">
```

hope this works for you

Comment: Hello to Stackoverflow! But you should check the code before you post. I have these 2 lines for the browser     <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">

     <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">

Comment: apology i did not check your code , i have opened the favicon image url directly in my browser and by just looking in it i thought its less than 16 , anyways ,
The favicon looks right when I visited your site. It is a little small, but that has to do with how much space your logo takes up within the image itself. If you want the favicon to be larger, you should crop the image so the edges are as close to your logo as possible.

Comment: here is a link i have adjust the picture for you .. just replace them in your folder
[link]http://ftp.sacodeco.net/main.html?download&weblink=27b4f2cd568258e46a05bacf1d4cbb9a&realfilename=favicomatic$20(1).zip [link]
@Mrmajik45

Comment: this is live version of your icon after adjust your favicon picture 

[link]http://mobiles.sacodeco.net/carscontracting/testfavicon.a5w [link] @Mrmajik45

Comment: Your ftp link won't load. i'm going to download it via your mobiles link

Comment: glad it worked .. i am sorry about the ftp link it seems that stackover comments wall removed part of it not sure anyways... i am so happy it worked for you . good luck whatever you are doing :)

Answer (score 0):

See my annotations in this image from invoking iOS’s Add to Homescreen option https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNoVG.jpg

My notes simply illustrate what [Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10253471/ahmed-shahin) already stated: you need to spend more time reworking the pixels in your favicon. Yes, it’s all about anti-aliasing and pushing pixels.